# Isolate a specific contour without Contour Shading

Tags: plotting

I have a contour plot that took a few hours to evaluate. Is there a way that I can show only the contour lines of a specific value without re-evaluating the contour plot?

Comment: Did you want the shading? The question's been changed to assume that you don't...

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
p = ContourPlot[Im[(x + I y)^(1/2)], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   Contours -> 21, ColorFunction -> Hue];

p /. {___, EdgeForm[___], ___} :> {}
```

[image: plot]

**Edit**

To **isolate** a contour line of a particular value, you could use `Tooltip` information in an automated way, but **let's assume that you don't have those enabled**.

Then how do you extract the desired contour? Here is a manual way that always works as long as you can visually pick out the contour you're interested in:

```
Graphics[Normal[p][[1]]]
```

[image: editor]

What I've done above is to display the graphic for the contour plot in a very bare-bones way. Then I double-clicked on the graphic to activate the **Drawing Tools**. They allow me to select a particular contour by double-clicking again. If you get the contour to be highlighted as above, you should be good to go for the next step:

Copy the highlighted contour the usual way (using `Edit` menu or shortcut), then type this:

```
Show[   , Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

Here, **paste** the copied graphic into the empty space in the first argument of `Show`.

Now you'll have the contour isolated, in exactly the right position relative to the frame that I re-created above.

[image: contour]

For this to work, it's important to convert the contour plot using `Normal` as I did above, so all objects have the information about their absolute coordinate placement.

Comment: There is just one thing to do... select the lines corresponding to one value only. But that should be possible by the tooltips. Or maybe even a better way?

Comment: @sebhofer I forgot that part... Question for the OP: did your original plot contain `Tooltp`s? That would allow you to identify the contour you want.

Comment: In that case I think one could use `p/.Tooltip[_, Except[label]] :> Sequence[]` to delete the unwanted lines...

Comment: @sebhofer That definitely works, *if* he has tooltips. I decided to answer in a different way in my edit.